Star chart with no constellation lines, and no star names
I want to find an online star chart website with an option to disable constellation lines and disable star names. I want to make flashcards of the constellations without lines or star names so I can recognize them on sight on the sky which would greatly improve my stargazing. I've found one before and memorized some of the constellations, but I want to find it again. Here's an image of a screenshot I took from the website
I can't find this website, though. What specific website is this?

That looks a bit like the graphics from https://stellarium-web.org/.

Not sure if the web version of Stellarium will let you disable all labels, but the desktop version will.  https://stellarium.org/

These aren't websites, so not an answer, but as well as Stellarium you might want to check out KStars, Cartes du Ciel, and MegaStar5. They're all highly customisable star chart software.
